# Match string with escape characters or backslashes

Tags: regex, perl

The following perl script and TestData simulate the situation where I can only find 2 instead of 4 expected. (to match all support.tier.1 with backslash in between).

How can I modify this perl regex here? thanks

```
my @TestData(
    "support.tier.1",
    "support.tier.2",
    qw("support\.tier\.1"),
    "support\.tier\.2",
    quotemeta("support.tier.1\@example.com"),
    "support.tier.2\@example.com",
    "support\.tier\.1\@example\.com",
    "support\.tier\.2\@example\.com",
    "sales\@example\.com"
);
```

Here is the code to be changed:

```
my $count = 0;
foreach my $tier(@TestData){
    if($tier =~ m/support.tier.1/){
        print "$count: $tier\n";
    }
    $count++;
}
```

I only get 2 matches while the expected is 4:

```
0: support.tier.1
6: support.tier.1@example.com
```

Comment: Why are you escaping and quoting the input values? Have you inspected the contents of `@tiers`? It should be fairly obvious why things aren't matching  when you look at the data...

Comment: Just to make my previous comment 100% clear, `.` in your regex pattern will match any single character. It will *not* match the string literal `\.`, which you've managed to create a couple times.

Comment: different setting return different values but should all contain support.tier.1, I have no control over other sources, just try to find all entries with the keyword, this is only the simulation trying to be similar to the real situation

Comment: Here, have a [mcve]: https://regex101.com/r/hK2dD5/1

Comment: @Gang what emails do you want to be accepted?

Comment: all entries contains support.tier.1 which is 4 in this case

Comment: @Gang No, there are not 4 strings that contain that substring, as I've shown in my example.

Comment: @MattJacob, if this  cannot be achieved by regex, any other methods is OK too, I only care about the final result, thanks

Comment: You can fix your regex by accounting for the backslash that exists sometimes (`support\\?\.tier\\?\.1`), but I really feel like you're not addressing the root cause. Your data should not be coming in escaped and quoted for use in a regular expression.

Comment: The root cause is different subs tried to accommodate different sendmail and postfix with dot, I might take the regex off if this is not the solution

Comment: @Matt Jacob, would you please post this 1 line and I will accept it and this is exactly what I am looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Since it seems that you may indeed be getting strings containing backslashes, I suggest that you use [`String::Unescape`](http://metacpan.org/module/String::Unescape) to remove those backslashes before testing your strings. You will probably have to install it as it isn't a core module

Your code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use String::Unescape;

my @tiers = (
  "support.tier.1",
  "support.tier.2",
  qw("support\.tier\.1"),
  "support\.tier\.2",
  quotemeta("support.tier.1\@example.com"),
  "support.tier.2\@example.com",
  "support\.tier\.1\@example\.com",
  "support\.tier\.2\@example\.com",
  "sales\@example\.com",
);

my $count = 0;

for my $tier ( @tiers ) {

  my $plain = String::Unescape->unescape($tier);

  if ( $plain =~ /support\.tier\.1/ ) {
    printf "%d: %s\n", ++$count, $tier;
  }
}
```

### output

```
1: support.tier.1
2: "support\.tier\.1"
3: support\.tier\.1\@example\.com
4: support.tier.1@example.com
```

Note that there is a bug in the `String::Unescape` module that prevents it from exporting the `unescape` function. It just means you have to use `String::Unescape::unescape` or `String::Unescape->unescape` all the time. Or you could import it manually with `*unescape = \&String::Unescape::unescape`

---

The `@tiers` array contains these exact strings

1. `support.tier.1`
2. `support.tier.2`
3. `"support\.tier\.1"`
4. `support.tier.2`
5. `support\.tier\.1\@example\.com`
6. `support.tier.2@example.com`
7. `support.tier.1@example.com`
8. `support.tier.2@example.com`
9. `sales@example.com`

Can you see that only items 1 and 7 contain the string `support.tier.1`? The other two that I imagine you expected to match are 3 and 5, which contain spurious backslashes

It's not clear, but it seems unlikely that you will be getting data in this format. If you really want to match `support.tier.1` where either dot may be preceded by a backslash character then you need `/support\\?\.tier\\?\.1/`, but I think you are misunderstanding the way Perl strings work

Comment: some sendmail vm servers are configured to accept format 3 and 5 for username with dot, that is why issue arises.  Thanks for showing me the clean and clean format.

Comment: @Gang: Please take a look at my revised solution, which may help you further

Answer (score 2):

I may not fully understand, but if I do I agree with the answer that Matt has already attempted to give you.  Regex definitely **can** handle your request if you are saying that the escape character may or may not be before each period in `support.tier.1`.

A single backslash is `\\` and `?` means essentially "one or zero:"

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tiers = (
  "support.tier.1",
  "support.tier.2",
  qw("support\.tier\.1"),
  "support\.tier\.2",
  quotemeta("support.tier.1\@example.com"),
  "support.tier.2\@example.com",
  "support\.tier\.1\@example\.com",
  "support\.tier\.2\@example\.com",
  "sales\@example\.com",
);

my $count = 0;

foreach my $tier (@tiers) {
  if ($tier =~ /support\\?.tier\\?.1/) {
    print "$count: $tier\n";
  }
  $count++;
}
```

On an unrelated note, for the purpose of creating an easy-to-follow example, I included a suggestion on how you might better format your sample data instead of using the `$str` and `push`es.

If this works, I'd recommend you ask Matt to post his comment responses as an answer and accept it.

Comment: this is exactly the answer I am looking for, and I totally agree with the format you proposed, I will ask Matt how to proceed following your instructions